# Java Applet Display Issue

Tags: java, applet, awt, layout-manager

The problem is with this program which calculates correctly and does output the information correctly, is that while it outputs the correct values, it does not display them correctly. They are randomly cut off or covered up partially. If I resize the applet window, even if i don't move it but just click the adjustment bar, it moves the output sentance and displays it correctly. Below is my Java code.

```
/* 
 *Programmer 
 *Project: Ohm's Law AKA the program of difficulties
 */ 

import java.awt. *; 
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ohmslaw extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
    Color seablue = new Color(70,191,243);
    Color white = new Color (250,250,250);
    Color black = new Color (0,0,0);
    Color NavyBlue = new Color (0,0,153);
    Color VegasGold = new Color (197,179,88); 
    Font fontOne = new Font("Century Schoolbook",Font.PLAIN, 16);
    Font fontTwo = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 16);
    Font fontThree = new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16);

    Label titleLabel = new Label ("The Ohm's Law calculator");
    Label noteLabel = new Label ("For all unknown values enter 0");
    Label voltagelabel = new Label ("Please enter the voltage");
    TextField voltageField = new TextField(10); 

    Label currentlabel = new Label ("Please enter the current"); 
    TextField currentField = new TextField(10); 

    Label resistancelabel = new Label ("Please enter the resistance"); 
    TextField resistanceField = new TextField(10); 

    Button calcButton = new Button("Calculate");
    Label calcLabel = new Label("Click calculate to output the other variable");

    Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");   
    Label clearLabel = new Label("Click the Clear Buttton to add new data.");

    Label newresistanceLabel = new Label ("                 ");
    Label newcurrentLabel = new Label ("                    ");
    Label newvoltageLabel = new Label ("                    ");
    Label blankarea = new Label ("                          "); 

    public void init()
    {
        setBackground(seablue);
        setForeground(white); 
        add(titleLabel); 
        add(noteLabel); 
        add(voltagelabel); 
        setForeground(black);
        add(voltageField);
        setForeground(white); 
        add(currentlabel); 
        setForeground(black);
        add(currentField);
        setForeground(white); 
        add(resistancelabel); 
        setForeground(black); 
        add(resistanceField);
        add(calcButton); 
        calcButton.addActionListener(this); 
        setForeground(white);
        setForeground(black); 
        add(clearButton);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        setForeground(white);
        add(clearLabel);

        add(newresistanceLabel);

        add(newcurrentLabel);

        add(newvoltageLabel); 

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double resistance;
        double current;
        double voltage; 

        if(e.getActionCommand() == "Calculate")
        {
            resistance = Double.parseDouble(resistanceField.getText());
            current = Double.parseDouble(currentField.getText());
            voltage = Double.parseDouble(voltageField.getText()); 

            if(resistance == 0)
            {
            doResistance(current, voltage); 

            }
            if(current == 0)
            {
                doCurrent(resistance, voltage);

            }   
            if(voltage == 0)
            {
                doVoltage(resistance, current);

            }
        }   
        if(e.getActionCommand() == "Clear")
        {
            voltageField.setText("");
            currentField.setText(""); 
            resistanceField.setText("");
            newresistanceLabel.setText ("      ");
            newcurrentLabel.setText ("         ");
            newvoltageLabel.setText("         ");
            calcLabel.setText("Click the Calculate Button to output your other value.");
            voltageField.requestFocus();
        }

    }


    public double doResistance(double current, double voltage)
    {
        double Rfinal;

            Rfinal = ((voltage)/(current));
            ResistanceOutput(current, voltage, Rfinal);
            return(0);

    } 
    public double doCurrent(double resistance, double voltage)
    {
        double Ifinal;

            Ifinal = ((voltage)/(resistance));
            CurrentOutput(resistance, voltage, Ifinal);
            return (0); 
    }
    public double doVoltage(double resistance, double current)
    {
        double Vfinal;

            Vfinal = ((resistance)*(current));
            VoltageOutput(resistance, current, Vfinal);
            return(0); 
    }

    public double ResistanceOutput(double current, double voltage, double Rfinal)
    {


        DecimalFormat two = new DecimalFormat(".0");

        newresistanceLabel.setForeground(white);
        newresistanceLabel.setText("Your Resistance is " 
            + two.format(Rfinal) + ".");
        return(0);
    }
    public double CurrentOutput(double resistance, double voltage, double Ifinal)
    {


                    DecimalFormat two = new DecimalFormat(".0");

        newcurrentLabel.setForeground(white);
        newcurrentLabel.setText("Your current is " 
            + two.format(Ifinal) + ".");
        return(0);
    }

    public double VoltageOutput(double resistance, double current, double Vfinal)
    {

        DecimalFormat two = new DecimalFormat(".0");

        newvoltageLabel.setForeground(white);
        newvoltageLabel.setText("Your voltage is " 
            + two.format(Vfinal) + ".");
        return(0);
    }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Image picture;
        picture = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "ohm.jpg");
        g.drawImage(picture, 55,350, this); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's 2013, time to move from AWT to Swing!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at some information on Java layouts. The Applet by default comes with the [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), which may not be what you want since it basically adds components side by side. Probably the best layout to use is [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Also, you may want to set a fixed size for your applet using the setSize method.

To make this more clear, if you wanted to use GridLayout (which is easier to use than GridBagLayout), you can add the following lines to your code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

//...

public void init(){
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2));

//your code for adding components...

this.setSize(550,250);//sets fixed size
}
```

This GridLayout will add all of your components to a 7x2 grid.